# What's the behaviour about android app backstack?

Tags: android, back-stack

Suppose that we have three Activities：A、B、C . And the entrance sequence is A -> B -> C.Normally when come back from C the sequensce is C -> B -> A. But  when in Activity C , I presss Home button to go to home screen . Will the app be killed after a long time ? If it will be killed , when i turn back to the app , the back sequence is still be correct ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the documentation found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

If your app is terminated, when restarted it will start without any history and there will not be a backstack and your app will go to Activity A, provided this is the default activity set in the manifest like so:

```
 <activity
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SplashScreen" >

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

(The above launches a splash screen in one of my apps and if it is terminated then this is the activity that starts)

To help further I have attached the lifecycle diagram:

[image: Android Activity Lifecycle]

As you can see if `onDestroy()` is called then the lifecycle of the app ends. When it starts again we would start a new lifecycle.

Comment: Notice that an app can be killed when other apps need memory. So it can be killed after a while.

Comment: Indeed, I was not mentioning that as this is discussed in detail lots of times before

Answer (score 0):

After you start your app when it was killed it opens the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

When an application is killed, it will start at the main activity which you have declared in your Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, because when your app while be killed the task-state of your app is not saved and will be return to Main activity  in your case this will be A

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `Activity` is **always in one** of the below mentioned states :

**i.** `Resumed:` The **activity is in Foreground**.

**ii.** `Paused :` **Another activity is in Foreground**, but `this activity` is **still visible**

**iii.** `Stopped:` This stopped activity is completely hidden.

**2.** Your case is `Stopped` state. The **system can kill** this stop activity by calling `finish()` method, or simply killing its process.

So you **start from the very beginning**, With **only A activity** in your Back-Stack